# Select all elements that don't have a child with 2 specific attributes

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have a problem with for xsl:foreach and the select xpath

```
<LIST>
  <ELEMENT name="QX25">
    <ELEMENT name="QX55A" value="1" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55B" value="2" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55C" value="xyz" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55D" value="dzy" />
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT name="QX55">
    <ELEMENT name="QX55A" value="1" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55B" value="2" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55C" value="xyz" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55D" value="dzy" />
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT name="QX55">
    <ELEMENT name="QX55A" value="2" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55B" value="1" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55C" value="dzy" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55D" value="xyz" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55E" value="X" />
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT name="QX55">
    <ELEMENT name="QX55A" value="3" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55B" value="2" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55C" value="xyz" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55E" value="X" />
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT name="QX55">
    <ELEMENT name="QX55A" value="4" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55B" value="3" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55C" value="xyz" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55E" value="P" />
  </ELEMENT>
</LIST>
```

I want to get all the LIST/ELEMENT with name QX55 that DO NOT have a child ELEMENT which name="QX55E" and value="X".
any other value is fine as well as not having a child ELEMENT with name="QX55E" at all.

This means I would like to have the following result:

```
  <ELEMENT name="QX55">
    <ELEMENT name="QX55A" value="1" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55B" value="2" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55C" value="xyz" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55D" value="dzy" />
  </ELEMENT>
  <ELEMENT name="QX55">
    <ELEMENT name="QX55A" value="4" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55B" value="3" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55C" value="xyz" />
    <ELEMENT name="QX55E" value="P" />
  </ELEMENT>
```

what I have tried:

```
<xsl:for-each select="/LIST/ELEMENT[@name='QX55']/ELEMENT[not(@name='QX55E'    and @value='X')]/../.">
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the path `/LIST/ELEMENT[@name='QX55'][not(ELEMENT[@name = 'QX55E' and @value = 'X' ])]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the count() function:

```
<xsl:for-each select=" /LIST/ELEMENT[ @name='QX55' and count( ELEMENT[ @name='QX55E' and @value='X' ] ) = 0 ] " >
```